# Chrome Ignoring Cache-Control no-store directive?

Tags: javascript, express, google-chrome

I have a web-app I'm allowing users to add scripts to. These scripts are written in JavaScript and run in the user's browser. When developing new scripts to run locally, I've added a button to the app that allows you to load it from a locally running web server, (i.e. so you'd click on it and enter http://path.to.my.pc:12345/script.js). My app will fetch this script and append to the DOM.

These scripts are assumed to be ES6 modules and Chrome happily handles those, recursively importing correctly.

However when running locally, I also wanted the ability for users to "refresh" as they're developing such that the app will hit their server again to redownload the scripts. Chrome does not seem to want to do this. Specifically, despite the fact that my local test server has specified no-store as Cache-Control, Chrome doesn't care. Even if I cacheBust script.js (i.e.http://blah/script.js?cb=randomInt), this cacheBust parameter is not recursively passed to the imports.

Here's the text of my locally running dev server:

```
const express = require("express");
const serveStatic = require("serve-static");
const morgan = require("morgan");

function setHeaders(res, path) {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
}

const app = express();
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(serveStatic('./', { setHeaders });

app.listen(12345);
```

Is there something else I can do? I really don't want to force my users to run webpack. The idea is to keep this as simple and stupid as possible so they can just focus on writing their scripts.

Edit Update: Checking 'Disable Caching' in Devtools also does not cause Chrome to actually... not cache.

Comment: Could it be that there is already a copy of the script in the browser's cache (inserted before you added the `Cache-Control` header)? `Cache-Control: no-store` prevents new cache entries, but does not prevent the browser from using existing ones (`Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store` would prevent both). It would also help if you show us the code that fetches and appends the script to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas :

- Have you prior to everything, do "developer tools > application >
  clear storage" to avoid using previous server instance cached ?
- Have you tried "Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store"  ?
- Have you tried on non Chrome browser ?
- Have you cleared all in client-side browser (ctr+alt+suppr) or hard
  reload (ctrl+shift+r) ?

I've the same need and in my node server i use

```
const nocache = require('nocache');
app.use(nocache());
app.set('etag', false);
```

And in client side, my query use only

```
'Cache-control', 'no-store'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing [ETag's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag)? along with your current headers?
The ETag specifies a version of the resource, if the version changes it should force the browser to revalidate it.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the script to a `scripts` folder and serve them with cache-control by setting maxAge option. Whenever a user refreshes it will load the file stored in his browsers cache:

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static('./scripts', { maxAge: 1000 }));
```

`{ maxAge: 1000 }` means that a HTTP response will remain in the user browser as a cached copy for the next 1000 seconds before it can be available for reuse.